# Connectivity between Cloud Run and Cloud SQL (Internal IP)

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, cloud-sql-proxy, google-vpc

I have created my organisation infrastructure in GCP following the [Cloud Foundation Toolkit](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/google-cloud-security-foundations-guide.pdf) using the [Terraform modules](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-example-foundation) provided by Google.

The following table list the IP ranges for all environments:

[image: VPC IP ranges]

Now I am in the process of deploying my application that consists of basically Cloud Run services and a Cloud SQL (Postgres) instance.
The Cloud SQL instance was created with a private IP from the "unallocated" IP range that is reserved for peered services (such as Cloud SQL).

In order to establish connectivity between Cloud Run and Cloud SQL, I have also created the Serverless VPC Connector (ip range 10.1.0.16/28) and configured the Cloud SQL proxy.

[image: Cloud Run Service]

When I try to connect to the database from the Cloud Run service I get this error after ~10s:

> CloudSQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run for additional details: Post "https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[my-project]/instances/platform-db/createEphemeral?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": context deadline exceeded

I have granted `roles/vpcaccess.user` for both the default Cloud Run SA and the one used by the application in the host project.

I have granted `roles/compute.networkUser` for both SAs in the service project. I also granted `roles/cloudsql.client` for both SAs.

I have enabled `servicenetworking.googleapis.com` and `vpcaccess.googleapis.com` in the service project.

I have run out of ideas and I can't figure out what the issue is.

It seems like a timeout error when Cloud Run tries to create a POST request to the Cloud SQL API. So it seems like the VPC connector (10.1.0.16/28) cannot connect to the Cloud SQL instance (10.0.80.0/20).

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the Cloud SQL built-in connexion in Cloud Run (but also App Engine and Cloud Function) a connexion similar to Cloud SQL proxy is created. This connexion can be achieved **only** on a Cloud SQL public IP, even if you have a serverless VPC connector and your database reachable through the VPC.

If you have only a private IP on Cloud SQL, you need to use the private IP to reach the database, not the built-in Cloud SQL connector. More detail in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#private-ip)

I also wrote [an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a)

Comment: I also tried with private IP, however the request times out with the error: HTTP 503 - The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.
Looking at the firewall, there is no ingress rules. Also, the routes look normal: there is one from the VPC connector range to the Shared VPC and from the Cloud SQL range to the peering VPC.
I believe I have the permissions well set up as well.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I found the issue. It was firewall rules missing. The Cloud Foundation Toolkit creates deny egress rules to all. The VPC connector is not in the range of the subnets and therefore don't get access by default. I created the firewall rule to allow egress to both the Private Services IP range in the Shared VPC and also to the Google APIs (199.36.153.8/30). However, I am not sure how to target the VPC connector. At the moment the newly created rules have 'all' as target. Is it possible to add network tags to the connector?

Comment: When you define your connector, you define a range. You can use this range in your firewall rule if you want. But no, you can't add a network tag to the connector.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a private IP, you need to check the docker bridge network's IP range. Here is what the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#timeout) says:

> If a client cannot connect to the Cloud SQL instance using private IP, check to see if the client is using any IP in the range 172.17.0.0/16. Connections fail from any IP within the 172.17.0.0/16 range to Cloud SQL instances using private IP. Similarly, Cloud SQL instances created with an IP in that range are unreachable. This range is reserved for the docker bridge network.

To resolve some of the issues, you are experiencing, follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues) and post any error messages you receive, for example, you could try:

> Try the [gcloud sql connect](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/connect) command to connect to your instance. This command authorizes your IP address for a short time. You can run this command in an environment with Cloud SDK and mysql client installed. You can also run this command in Cloud Shell, which is available in the Google Cloud Console and has Cloud SDK and the mysql client pre-installed.

> Temporarily allow all IP addresses to connect to an instance. For IPv4 authorize 0.0.0.0/0 (for IPv6, authorize ::/0. ***After you have tested this, please make sure you remove it again as it opens up to the world!***

Are you using [connection pools](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#pools)?

If not, I would create a cache of connections so that when your application needs to link to the database, it can get a temporary connection from the pool. Once the application has finished its operation, the connection returns to the pool again for later use. For this to work correctly, the connection needs to be [open and closed efficiently](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#opening_and_closing_connections) and not waste any resources.